# Why am I getting a unreported exception java.net.MalformedURLException when I'm throwing it already?

Tags: java, http, malformedurlexception

Disclaimer: I haven't done Java in a long while.

I created this singleton class to create an HttpURLConnection.

```
public class EstablishConnection {
    HttpURLConnection conn = setupConn("some url");
    private static final EstablishConnection instance = new EstablishConnection();
    
    //private constructor to avoid client applications to use constructor
    private EstablishConnection(){}
​
    public static EstablishConnection getInstance(){
        return instance;
    }
    
    private static HttpURLConnection setupConn(String addr) throws MalformedURLException, IOException, ProtocolException {
        URL url = new URL(addr);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        return conn;
    }
}
​
```

Why am I getting an unreported `MalformedURLException` exception when I'm throwing it in `setupConn`?

```
|       HttpURLConnection conn = setupConn("some url");
unreported exception java.net.MalformedURLException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

Comment: You have it at throws on the method signature, but that also means the call can throw that Exception. The error is on the call, not on the method itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are throwing the exception from  setupConn function but you are not handling the thrown exception when you are calling it here :

```
HttpURLConnection conn = setupConn("some url");
```

you can handle the exception using try catch in the setupConn function or you can call the function in the the constructor and then rethrow from there.